# How to Pull from specific changeset

Tags: mercurial, hgsubversion

Recently I am working on Mercurial Repository. But I don't know how to pull version control from specific change-set ID on Mercurial ? Could you please share me any solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `-r` option, to pull the changeset and all its ancestors:

```
hg pull -r <hash>
```

Alternatively, use the `-b <branch>` option to get a specific branch.

Comment: this literally has no effect, current commit does not forward to new one, it does nothing

Answer (score -1):

First pull the source:

```
hg pull
```

Then update to specific revision:

```
hg up -r <changeset number>
```

Comment: This pulls the entire source, all of its change sets. This is not what OP asked for.